# Is it idiomatic to say "my phone runs on battery" and "my phone uses battery"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

Dictionary says "**[Our van runs on (= uses) diesel.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/run_1?q=run)**".

Similarly, can we say?

- "**my phone runs on battery**" and "**my phone uses battery**"
- "**the fan runs on electricity**" and "**the fan uses electricity**"

Comment: The phone runs on electricity too - the battery is just the means of storing the electricity. You can say 'My phone uses **a** battery' or 'is powered by a battery'.

Comment: Where have you read *my phone runs on battery*?

Comment: @KateBunting, "battery" (uncountable) also means "**electrical power that comes from a battery**" (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/battery?q=battery). For example, "**my phone ran out of battery**". The question is why I can't say "**my phone runs on battery**"?

Comment: I suppose **my phone ran out of battery** is just an informal way of saying **the battery in my phone ran out of power**. There is no logical reason why we don't say _my phone runs on battery_ - we just don't.

Comment: You need to specify BrE up there in the question. Otherwise you will get questions and advice from people who never say *my phone ran out of battery*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phone runs on electricity too - the battery is just the means of storing the electricity. You can say 'My phone uses a battery' or 'is powered by a battery'. – Kate Bunting

Or you can say "My phone runs on electricity".

Comment: converting a comment

Comment: Just to add some explanation of why: electricity is a mass noun, so you use it in the singular with no article. Battery is a count noun, so you could say your phone runs on a battery, and your TV remote control, which uses two batteries at the same time, runs on batteries.

Comment: @tea-and-cake, but "battery" is uncountable too when it means "electrical power that comes from a battery" (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/battery?q=battery). For example, "**my phone ran out of battery**"

Comment: Very good point @Tom, I was thinking the same myself after I posted that.  You could also  have "my hybrid car has run out of fuel and is now running on battery".

Comment: By the way, @tea-and-cake this is a community wiki, so if you want to add some explanation of "why" just click [edit]